# Modifying Amazon API image URL with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting the LargeImage URL using Amazon's advertising API. I want to modify the URL to replace

```
.jpg
```

with

```
._SS300_.jpg
```

to show the correct size I need for my template. I am using Wordpress and a plugin called AmazonSimpleAdmin.

I believe this is the part of the plugin code I need to do something to:

```
$replace = array(
  // ...   
  ($item->LargeImage != null) ? $item->LargeImage->Url->getUri() :
  get_bloginfo('wpurl') . $this->plugin_dir . '/img/no_image.gif',
```

I don't know much PHP, but as far as I can tell the large image URL is part of the array, and I know the part I need to change is

```
$item->LargeImage->Url->getUri()
```

but that's as much as I've been able to figure out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = '.jpg';
$string = str_replace('.jpg', '._SS300_.jpg', $string);
// Do something with $string.
```

Comment: Not sure what to do with that. I can't just insert that into the array there, can I? The URL returned is a full url, so would the full URL be in $string?

Comment: Yes, `$string = 'http://site.com/image.jpg';` and it will replace the .jpg with ._SS300_.jpg .

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it to work by putting this at the end of the array:
   
`$replace = str_replace( ".jpg", "._SS300_.jpg", $replace );`

However, this affects all the array items, not just LargeImage. So I added this after the first str_replace:

`$replace = str_replace( "._SL160_._SS300_.jpg", "._SS160_.jpg", $replace );`

This does fix it for me, but it's a messy fix isn't it. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I need to see the whole code, I can't help you with this little piece of code.